# mpdf 7.0 - Issue with combination of adding File-Extension and Showing file inline

Tags: php, http, mpdf

I'm creating a dynamic pdf file-name based on field in a form submitted by user. And I tried with two cases with destination as inline.

**Case 1:** When file extension is not added/hardcoded - file generated shows in-line in any desktop browser (all latest Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge).

```
$mpdf->Output($name . ' - (' . date('dMY') . ')', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE);
```

**Case 2:** When file extension is added/hardcoded - file generated starts downloading instead of showing inline in any desktop browser (all latest Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge).

```
$mpdf->Output($name . ' - (' . date('dMY') . ').pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE);
```

In case 1, it shows file inline but after downloading (using download option within embedded pdf), file doesn't have any extension. In case 2, it automatically starts downloading along with proper extension instead of showing it inline. In tablet & mobile browsers it always starts downloading instead of showing it inline.

Is there any way to show it inline, along with adding proper extension once downloaded? Also how to make it show inline in tablets and mobile browsers?

Comment: Can you add complete HTTP response headers of each case to your question?

Comment: -----Case 1 (without adding/hardcoding file extension)-----


cache-control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0, cf-ray: 3cb5817b99430a78-LHR, content-disposition: inline; filename="Vishwas - (11Dec2017)", content-type: application/pdf, date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017, 04:25:01 GMT, expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT, last-modified: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 04:524:36 GMT, pragma: public, server: cloudflare-nginx, X-Firefox-Spdy: h2, x-generator: mPDF 7.0.0, x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.23

Comment: -----Case 2 (with hardcoded file-extension)-----


cache-control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0, cf-ray: 3cb5bf3f3ec934e2-LHR, content-disposition: inline; filename="Vishwas - (11Dec2017).pdf", content-type: application/pdf, date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 04:37:10 GMT, expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT, last-modified: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 04:36:45 GMT, pragma: public, server: cloudflare-nginx, X-Firefox-Spdy: h2, x-generator: mPDF 7.0.0, x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.23